# Method Variables in singleton pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, singleton

Am new to Spring.I have a spring bean countService which is a singleton

```
public class CountService {
    private int doCount() {
        String commentsText = null;
        List tranIds = new ArrayList();
        int count = 0;
        // ---business logic----

        return count;
    }
}
```

Are the method variables commentsText,tranIds thread-safe?Thanks in advance

Comment: depends on what you're doing in the business logic. This code is thread safe, though, because all the variables are local

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring or not, Java *local* variables are thread safe as long as you do not share their objects manually with other threads. For example, if your "business logic" code creates new threads and passes your local variables to these threads, the locals are not thread safe. Other than that, they are: each executing thread running your method will get its own local variable that is separate from all other local variables.

Answer (score 3):

If no state at all is shared between threads, then the code is thread-safe.

So if all you have is local variables, the method is thread-safe. Of course, if these local variables are in fact references to shared objects, and these shared objects are not thread safe, then you have a problem.

But if all the objects the method uses are created by the method itself, then nothing is shared, and you're safe.

Example of thread safe code:

```
 public int foo(String a, String b) {
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); // the list is local to the method
     // do some work with the list
     return list.size();
 }
```

Example of non-thread-safe code:

```
 public int foo(String a, String b) {
     List<String> list = SomeClass.getSomeStaticListReference(); // the list is shared between threads
     // do some work with the list
     return list.size();
 }
```